# How to validate bearer access token in spring boot using jwt public key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I have access token generated from websec using client id and secret.

My project app.properties have jwt public key.

I am developing rest api , call to Rest api will provide Bear token (generated one)that I wanted to validate using jwt public key.

But spring security internally use in memory token validator and return invalid token.

So how can l use jwt public key to validate the bearer token.

Or here I lack some understanding.

Comment: Take a look at this great article about Spring Boot + JWT: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world